# NSPredicate that can grab a one to many relationship entity with @max value

Tags: swift, core-data, nspredicate

I have setup where I have the entities `Student` and `Attendance` where a student can have many attendances and each attendance can only have one student. Each attendances has a date called `attendanceAt` that represented the date the attendance is from.

`Attendance<->>Student`

I want to make a query on `Students` that grabs all the students whos last Attendance falls between two dates. I also want the last attendance direction to be "in".

This is what i got so far:

I can check if the most recent attendance between two dates by using @max.

```
NSPredicate(format: "attendances.@max.attendanceAt < %@ AND attendances.@max.attendanceAt > %@", date1! as CVarArg, date2! as CVarArg)
```

My issue is that `attendances.@max.attendanceAt` returns the date and not the Attendance entity. Because of this I cannot do something like `attendances.@max.attendanceAt.direction == "in"`

I have also tried messing around with  `SUBQUERY()`like so:

```
NSPredicate(format: "SUBQUERY(attendances, $att, 
                   $att.attendanceAt < %@ 
               AND $att.attendanceAt > %@ 
               AND $att.attendanceAt == attendances.@max.attendanceAt
               AND $att.direction == %@
             ).@count > 0",
 date1! as CVarArg, date2! as CVarArg, "in")
```

Which does work and anytime I try and do anything with @max inside SUBQUERY the app crashes.

Any ideas on how to accomplish what I want with NSPredicate?